# Fabric:Python as ???:Javascript

Tags: django, node.js, heroku, fabric

I have been using [Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) to do deployment for a Django app.  I am using some node.js stuff now and am looking to see if there is a tool that does what Fabric did for python - but that is built mainly for javascript and node.

My main use case is to save everything to git and deploy to heroku by just typing `fab deploy` - but for node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [NodeJS](https://github.com/VanCoding/NodeSSH/blob/master/examples/sample.js) or [node-control](https://github.com/tsmith/node-control). Both are node.js ssh clients.